# What pen to use for autograph on guitar, and how to protect it?

Tags: guitar, maintenance

I am getting a [1997 Gibson SG Special (Black)](https://www.elderly.com//media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/600x600/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/1/p1147887.jpg) signed next month by one of my favorite artists.

What sort of pen should I use for this specific guitar? I had read acrylic pen, but I am not sure. I want it in silver. I figured by providing the exact make/model of guitar, someone will know the best type of pen.

After I get it signed, how can I ensure it is protected permanently? I read about clear wrap, but I am not hot on that idea. I've also read about people applying a varnish or lacquer... with success and horror stories.

What do I do?

Answer (score 5):

On a black guitar you're going to need a white, silver or gold marker.

That is going to cause issues if you want to over-coat it afterwards.

Metallic markers are 'solvent-based' but will stay on the surface, not soak into the surface like those big black marker pens you sniff at, wondering if they could make you high (joke) - but without knowing precisely what solvent it went on with you're not going to know what 'solvent' won't turn it into a mushy smudge when you coat it..

Solution - water-based lacquer.

Art & craft shop is going to be your best source for that. Available as a spray.

Even coated, it **will** scratch off if you're not careful, so if you want it to last a lifetime, you're going to be hanging it on a wall, not gigging with it.